# Jetpack Compose Google Maps ClusterItem position is centered at the bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

*I filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/324), but maybe there is a workaround which I am seeking here*

I am using `Clustering` and to my suprise, the content of the `ClusterItem` is not centered in the middle, but at the bottom. This square and marker have the exact same position, but as you can see the square is not in the center of the marker. This looks really weird and wrong when you place `ClusterItems` with images on the map, they are on top of where they belong:

[image]

Reproduction project:
https://github.com/Jasperav/GoogleMapsBug

Relevant code:

```
GoogleMap(cameraPositionState = CameraPositionState(
    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
        defaultLocation, 18f
    )
)) {
    Marker(state = MarkerState(defaultLocation))
    Clustering(items = listOf(ClusterItemCustom())) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredHeight(100.dp)
                .requiredWidth(100.dp)
                .background(
                    Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the preferred behavior, as the user expects the marker to be directly above the location. This is a standard UI expectation. Whats your use-care?

Comment: @RealityExpander I am rewriting iOS code to Kotlin and in iOS, the default behavior is that items you put on a map are centered.

Comment: OK, but you must realize that Compose comes from JetBrains, which is starting from Android and Google, who created Google Maps... right?